# Fetching data from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

The below line of code is fetching only one Name per city where  as there are many names per city.

**Code**

```
function getNames() {
$data = array();
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$qdata = $db->prepare("SELECT City, Name from CityRecord where Year = ?");
$qdata->bind_param("s", '2019');
$qdata->execute();
$qdata->bind_result($City, $Name);
while($qdata->fetch()) {
      $data[$City] = array("Name" => $Name);
}
print_r($data);
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
City1
   Name1
   Name2
City2
   Name1
   Name2
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Change it to `$data[$City][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use multidimension field.

Try this:

```
function getNames() {
    $data = array();
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    $qdata = $db->prepare("SELECT City, Name from CityRecord where Year = ?");
    $qdata->bind_param("s", '2019');
    $qdata->execute();
    $qdata->bind_result($City, $Name);
    while ($qdata->fetch()) {
        $data[$City][] = array("Name" => $Name);
    }
    //print_r($data);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your solution, but you didn't read the rest of the code. This code has more problems than the one you tried to address. When answering it is best to provide complete answers.